# How do I find $\int \frac{xe^{x}}{(x+1)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to learn calc 2 before college and was doing the practice problems in the fourth edition of Larson and Edward's calculus textbook. The problem set I'm doing is right after the book introduced integration by parts, but the questions don't necessarily require integration by parts.

The problem written is basically $\int \frac{xe^{x}}{(x+1)^2}dx$, and I wasn't able to find a way to solve it with the tools given to me at this point in the book (It taught us u-substitution, integration by parts, trig identities, and basic algebra stuff like completing the square)

I did a u-substitution by letting $u=1+x$, $du=dx$, $x=u-1$

$$\implies \int \frac{xe^{x}}{(x+1)^2}dx=\int \frac{(u-1)e^{u-1}}{u^2}du=\int u^{-1}e^{u-1}-u^{-2}e^{u-1}$$

I had tried a lot of things at this point, but I really had no idea. After seeing the solution in the back of the book (it just gave the answer, not how to solve it), I realized that $\int u^{-1}e^{u-1}-u^{-2}e^{u-1}$ is the derivative of a product, so:

$$\int u^{-1}e^{u-1}-u^{-2}e^{u-1}=u^{-1}e^{u-1}+C=\frac{e^x}{x+1}+C$$

However, this isn't really like anything the book has shown at this point, so I think another way is intended. It is relating to the derivative of a product, so I assume you can use integration by parts at some point, but I have no idea where it would work. I also considered that you could do some sort of infinite series, but the book also hasn't gotten to that. If anyone would be able to help, that would be awesome!

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate $\int{\frac{xe^x}{(1+x)^2} dx}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886429/evaluate-int-fracxex1x2-dx) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint%5Cfrac%7Bxe%5E%7Bx%7D%7D%7B(x%2B1)%5E2%7Ddx%24&p=1). There are also other related questions, e.g., [When is LIATE simply wrong?](/q/1620724).

Comment: To give an explanation for what actually happened, when you "noticed" that the expression you had was the derivative of a product, you were actually doing integration by parts in disguise. Or rather, integration by parts is actually doing the inverse operation of product rule. You can do the by-parts normally on the expression you had earlier to see why this works.

Comment: You basically unknowingly used that $\int e^x(f(x)+f'(x)) \mathrm{d} x = e^xf(x) + C$. This is nothing but a result of using integration by parts.